# C++/CLI wrapper LNK2028 and LNK2019 error

Tags: c++, dll, c++-cli, dllimport, lnk

I need following function (from C++ dll) available in C++/CLI

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall DestroyInstance(CKeyManagerServerApp *ptr);
```

My try:

```
[DllImport("KeyManagerServer.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention::StdCall)]
void DestroyInstance(CKeyManagerServerApp IntPtr);
```

The C++/CLI wrapper is compiled with /clr and stdcall (C++ dll also with stdcall)!

I got following errors:

```
MKeyManagerInterface.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000585) "extern "C" void __stdcall DestroyInstance(class CKeyManagerServerApp *)" (?DestroyInstance@@$$J14YGXPAVCKeyManagerServerApp@@@Z) referenced in function "private: __clrcall MKeyManagerInterface::ManagedKeyInterface::~ManagedKeyInterface(void)" (??1ManagedKeyInterface@MKeyManagerInterface@@$$FA$AAM@XZ)
1>MKeyManagerInterface.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __stdcall DestroyInstance(class CKeyManagerServerApp *)" (?DestroyInstance@@$$J14YGXPAVCKeyManagerServerApp@@@Z) referenced in function "private: __clrcall MKeyManagerInterface::ManagedKeyInterface::~ManagedKeyInterface(void)" (??1ManagedKeyInterface@MKeyManagerInterface@@$$FA$AAM@XZ)
1>..\Debug\Bin\KeyManagerInterfaceD.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

How can I solve this linker errors?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use P/Invoke from C++/CLI. You should be able to include the usual C/C++ header files that declare the imported function. Just make sure to link your C++/CLI assembly against the export library from the native-code DLL that exports the function in question.

Comment: Yes, but if I want to load the library at runtime linking against lib is not suitable!

Comment: @leon22 But you never stated that as a requirement in your post :)  Can you just use `LoadLibrary` + `GetProcAddress` like unmanaged Windows C/C++ code does?

Comment: Yes, this was my first idea! But I'm always getting strange memory errors! see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306602/heap-error-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you've got heap corruption issues, you should work on resolving them regardless of this loading problem. (I also don't understand how `LoadLibrary` relates to heap corruption.) Perhaps you could try using tools like `Application Verifier` to help catch heap issues?

Comment: Thx! It was only an idea! I will try with Application Verifier!